# Why wrong output from the RegEx?

Tags: perl

When I run the script below, I get

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ok0.ok]][[file:ok1.ok',
          undef,
          undef,
          'ok2.ok|dgdfg]][[file:ok3.ok',
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

where I was hoping for `ok0.ok ok1.ok ok2.ok ok3.ok` and ideally also `ok4.ok ok5.ok ok6.ok ok7.ok`

**Question**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $html = "sdfgdfg[[file:ok0.ok]][[file:ok1.ok ]] [[file:ok2.ok|dgdfg]][[file:ok3.ok |dfgdfgg]] [[media:ok4.ok]] [[media:ok5.ok ]] [[media:ok6.ok|dgdfg]] [[media:ok7.ok |dfgdfgg]]ggg";

my @seen = ($html =~ /file:(.*?) |\||\]/g);

print Dumper \@seen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to match everything starting with `file:` and ending with either a space, a pipe or a closing square bracket.

Your OR-statement at the end of the regexp needs to be between (square) brackets itself though:

```
my @seen = ($html =~ /file:(.*?)[] |]/g);
```

If you want the media: blocks as well, OR the file part. You might want a non-capturing group here:

```
my @seen = ($html =~ /(?:file|media):(.*?)[] |]/g);
```

#### How it works

The first statement will capture everything between 'file:' and a `]`, `|` or .

The second statement does the same, but with both *file* and *media*. We use a non-capturing group `(?:group)` instead of `(group)` so the word is not put into your `@seen`.

Comment: Very interesting. Is it on purpose that you say `(.*?)[\]|\]| ]` instead of `(.*?)[\]\| ]` ?

Comment: While your solution will do what is required, you seem to misunderstand the way character classes work. Your original regex had `[\]|\]| ]` which matches any of the list close bracket, pipe, close bracket, pipe, or space. Your revision now matches pipe, pipe, close bracket, pipe, or space. All you require is `[] |]` which matches close bracket, pipe, or space.

Comment: @Borodin: I indeed confused character class with group. No need for the pipe to OR characters in a character class `[]`. Thanks!

Comment: Now I am confused. Why doesn't Perl complain about unbalanced bracket with `(.*?)[] |]` ? I mean, how does it know that the first `]` is meant as a character to be matched, and not the end of character class?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting - pease read Section: _Special Characters Inside a Bracketed Character Class_ in [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)

Answer (score 2):

A negated character class can simplify things a bit, I think.  Be explicit as to your anchors (file:, or media:), and explicit as to what terminates the sequence (a space, pipe, or closing bracket).  Then capture.

`my @seen = $html =~ m{(?:file|media):([^\|\s\]]+)}g;`

Explained:

```
my @seen = $html =~ m{
    (?:file|media):        # Match either 'file' or 'media', don't capture, ':'
    ( [^\|\s\]]+ )         # Match and capture one or more, anything except |\s]
}gx;
```

Capturing stops as soon as `]`, `|`, or `\s` is encountered.

Comment: `[^\|\s\]]` reduces to `[^]\s|]` (or `[^] |]` if you can't stand backspaces in char classes ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
my @seen = ($html =~ /\[\[\w+:(\w+\.\w+)\]\]/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what your regex does:

```
 ...
 my $ss = qr {
              file: # start with file + column as anchor
              (         # start capture group
               .*?      # use any character in a non-greedy sweep
              )         # end capture group
              \s        # end non-greedy search on a **white space**

              |     # OR expression encountered up to here with:
              \|     # => | charachter  
              |      # OR expression encountered up to here with:
              \]       # => ] charachter  
              }x;

 my @seen = $html =~ /$ss/g;
 ...
```

and this is what your regex is supposed to do:

```
 ...
 my $rb = qr {
             \w :      # alphanumeric + column as front anchor
             (         # start capture group 
              [^]| ]+  # the terminating sequence
             )         # end capture group 
            }x;

 my @seen = $html =~ /$rb/g;
 ...
```

If you want a short, concise regex and know what you do, you could drop the capturing group altogether and use full capture chunk in list context together with positive lookbehind:

```
 ...
 my @seen = $html =~ /(?<=(?:.file|media):)[^] |]+/g; # no cature group ()
 ...
```

or, if no other structure in your data as shown is to be dealt with, use the `:` as only anchor:

```
 ...
 my @seen = $html =~ /(?<=:)[^] |]+/g;   # no capture group and short
 ...
```

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the possible characters in the file name, I think you probably want

```
my @seen = $html =~ /(?:file|media):([\w.]+)/g;
```

which captures all of `ok0.ok` through to `ok7.ok`.

It relies on the file names containing alphanumeric characters plus underscore and dot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you required.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;  

use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


my $string = "sdfgdfg[[file:ok0.ok]][[file:ok1.ok ]] [[file:ok2.ok|dgdfg]][[file:ok3.ok |dfgdfgg]] [[media:ok4.ok]] [[media:ok5.ok ]] [[media:ok6.ok|dgdfg]] [[media:ok7.ok |dfgdfgg]]ggg";

my @matches;

@matches = $string =~ m/ok\d\.ok/g;

print Dumper @matches;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = 'ok0.ok';

$VAR2 = 'ok1.ok';

$VAR3 = 'ok2.ok';

$VAR4 = 'ok3.ok';

$VAR5 = 'ok4.ok';

$VAR6 = 'ok5.ok';

$VAR7 = 'ok6.ok';

$VAR8 = 'ok7.ok';
```

Regards,
Kiran.